# C++ Open a file in main to be read by a function

Tags: c++

UPDATE: I knew it had to be something simple and stupid. After trying so many things I finally realized that I had void in my function call. That was the biggest problem all along. Thanks to all who helped me realize my stupidity.

I am very new to this and see that the style I'm learning from the book I have is much different than what I'm seeing on this site. This isn't homework, but is an exercise from D.S Malik 5th addition.

I can't seem to get my code pasted on this site correctly so I will just grab a few spots so you can get an idea of where I'm at. I'm altering a program I wrote previously so that I open a file in main, and read it from my function. How do I do this... as in how do I read from function what was opened in main? That's the part holding me back from changing the rest.  Thanks so much for any help.

UPDATE: I still can't copy and paste the whole program for some reason, but here are more clips of my code. I tried istream and ifstream in the function. I also tried using inData and inDat. Here are the errors I get for what I've pasted:
error C2182: 'getNumber' : illegal use of type 'void'
error C2078: too many initializers
error C2182: 'getNumber' : illegal use of type 'void'
error C2078: too many initializers

Currently read in main as:

```
inData >> number;
```

What I need to change is the old version in my function that is:

```
void getNumber(int& num)
{cin >> num;//!!!!!!!!!Can't use inData input variable here}


void initialize(int& zeroCount, int& oddCount, int& evenCount);
void getNumber(std::istream& inDat, int& num);
void classifyNumber(int num, int& zeroCount, int& oddCount, int& evenCount);
void printResults(int zeroCount, int oddCount, int evenCount);
int main()
```

{

```
int counter; 
int number;
int zeros;
int odds;
int evens;
int randNum;
int i;
int r;
string numList;
ifstream inData;
ofstream outData;
inData.open("random.txt");
outData.open("results.txt");
initialize(zeros, odds, evens);

counter = 1;
void getNumber(inData, number);
while (!inData.eof())
{
    if (counter == 10)
    {
        cout << endl;
        outData << endl;
    }
    cout << setw(4) << number;
    outData << setw(4) << number;
    classifyNumber(number, zeros, odds, evens);
    counter++;
    void getNumber(inData, number);
    if (counter > 20)
    {
        cout << "Error in while loop \"Processing Data\"" << endl;
        break;
    }
} // end while

cout << endl;
printResults(zeros, odds, evens);
cin.sync();
cin.ignore();
return 0;
```

}

```
void initialize(int& zeroCount, int& oddCount, int& evenCount)
{
zeroCount = 0;
oddCount = 0;
evenCount = 0;
```

}

```
void getNumber(std::istream& inDat, int& num)
{
inDat >> num;
```

}

Comment: Could you paste the lines you used to actually open the file (not just to read it)? It probaby creates a file descriptor or a streaming object you could pass to your function as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `getNumber` to take a `std::istream&` as an argument.

```
void getNumber(std::istream& inData, int& num);
```

and change its implementation to:

```
void getNumber(std::istream& inData, int& num)
{
   inData >> num;
}
```

Change the place where it gets called to:

```
getNumber(inData, num);
```

Comment: I would suggest the redefinition of `void getNumber` to `int getNumber`, and call the function like so: `num = getNumber(inData)`. I believe this assignment style is to be preferred.

Comment: @VicenteCunha, the advantage of using `void getNumber(... int&)` is that it allows for the overload `void getNumber(..., double&)`.

Comment: @VicenteCunha also by passing in a reference to num along with a reference to an istream object the function is also more efficient, slightly quicker and uses less memory; it doesn't have to make a stack copy of the variable passed in since it is using references.